# elastic textarea css issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/r3Ekw/3854/

when the elastic textarea in the chat container start to take effect you can see the bug in it's style and how the content is under the bottom and not visible

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#txt_chat_msg").elastic();
  $("#elastictxt").elastic();
});
```

css

```
.Chat_Footer_Container
{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  border-top:1px solid #868686;
  background-color:White;
}
 .Chat_Footer_Container textarea 
{
  width:92%;
  /*height:75%; */
  position:relative;
  border:none;
  bottom:0px;
  resize:none;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *take effect*??

Comment: when you start typing and the textarea start to change it's height